# Good book for general topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I want a book in general topology with many interesting and hard exercises. I mean a book with topics the same as Munkres  but with challenging questions to improve my problem solving ability.

Comment: Willard's General Topology (it's also a dover book so can be found dirt cheap)

Comment: You can also have a look at other threads with book recommendations for general topology, which are mentioned here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions

Answer (score 0):

I really like "Topology without tears" by Sidney Morris.

Although there are some topics in Munkres that it doesn't cover, this is a very nice book. Great explanations and examples, and a lot of exercises (some of them are very challenging).